# Mirror to remote git repo over proxied ssh

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

I'm trying to setup a git push only mirror and I'm a little confused as how to proceed.  The confusing part becomes that I need to access the server via SSH via a proxied host.

In my `.ssh/config` i have the following entry:

```
Host remoteHost
  HostName machine3
  User demo
  ProxyCommand ssh -l <username> bastion nc %h 22
```

So if I do `ssh remoteHost` it first logs into `bastion` with my user account and then will connect from `bastion` to `machine3` with username `demo`

I believe I want to setup a bare repo on `machine3` and then setup a remote on my local machine - but I'm a little unclear how to proceed

Here is what I've done thus far.  First I setup a bare repo on `machine3`

```
// Setup the bare repo
ssh remoteHost
cd /devel/repo
git init --git-dir=testRepo1 init --bare
```

Then I tried to go to an existing cloned repo on my local machine

```
git remote add --mirror remote remoteHost:/devel/repo/testRepo1
git push remote --mirror
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working the way i hoped, it seems to log in via the proxy host but sort of just sits there.

Any help?